# Sampling a multivariate t distribution with less than 2 degrees of freedom

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I need to sample from a multivariate t-distribution with less than 2 degrees of freedom.

This article on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution#Definition) shows that a multivariate t-distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom can be defined as follows:
$$X = \mu + \sqrt{W}AZ \sim t_\nu(\mu, \Sigma) $$
where $W=\nu/\chi_{\nu}^2$ and $\chi_{\nu}^2$ is a random variable following a chi-squared distribution with $\nu>0$ degrees of freedom, $Z\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ is a normal random vector with independent components. Note that $\chi_{\nu}^2$ is independent of $Z$.

But since $\nu<2$, the covariance matrix of $X$ (i.e. $\Sigma$) does not exist, and therefore I cannot sample $Z$.

Is there another method I should be using for sampling? How can I sample a t distribution with less than 2 degrees of freedom?

Comment: Most simulations are based on the LLN, which requires finite variance. What attribute of the multivariate t are you trying to simulate? Is there an analogue that can be tested with the univariate t so you can check stability at least in that special case? // If you decide the project is valid, then perhaps use Metropolis-Hastings; I think you will have trouble finding a valid majorizing function for simpler acceptance-rejection methods.

Comment: First it depends on which multivariate generalization you are referring to. Once you have chosen one, and if you know its joint pdf, I think you can use acceptance rejection.